# FFMPEG: closing RTSP stream cleanly -- av_read_frame crash on avformat_close_input

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm using KxMovie: https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie

It appears to stop a stream and close the view controller one should use [pause];
However, I'm trying to receive a stream from a version of gstreamer that has a memory leak if a stream isn't closed properly (it's just left hanging).

So, just [pause]ing isn't an option for me.

I'm trying to use [closeFile] in the KxMovie decoder:

```
-(void) closeFile
{

[self closeAudioStream];
[self closeVideoStream];
[self closeSubtitleStream];

_videoStreams = nil;
_audioStreams = nil;
_subtitleStreams = nil;

     if (_formatCtx) {
         _formatCtx->interrupt_callback.opaque = NULL;
         _formatCtx->interrupt_callback.callback = NULL;
         avformat_close_input(&_formatCtx);
         _formatCtx = NULL;
     }
}
```

However, I usually get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS from av_read_frame after [closeFile] issues avformat_close_input.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to cleanly shutdown an RTSP stream using ffmpeg?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Needed to use the interrupt callbacks to interrupt av_read_frame

```
        _formatCtx->interrupt_callback.opaque
        _formatCtx->interrupt_callback.callback
```

Wait for the callback to be called and return non zero. 
After the callback has returned an interrupt value av_close_input can safely be called (after closing any codecs used).

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about this ? What did you do in the callbacks, what are the method signatures? I'd like to cleanly close an rtsp stream, but what exactly do I have to release? Where, how ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused by this, and I do not quite understand your solution.

I fixed it like below, could you give some advice?

_dispatchQueue is the same queue as doing asyncDecodeFrames work.

```
- (void)unSetup {

    _buffered = NO;
    _interrupted = YES;

    dispatch_async(_dispatchQueue, ^{
        if (_decoder) {

            [self pause];
            [self freeBufferedFrames];

            if (_moviePosition == 0 || _decoder.isEOF)
                [gHistory removeObjectForKey:_decoder.path];
            else if (!_decoder.isNetwork)
                [gHistory setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_moviePosition]
                            forKey:_decoder.path];

            [_decoder closeFile];
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code snippets are in Objective-C and the implementation file `.m` is for the object that handles RTSP stuff (`RTSPProvider`).

It is tested with Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61) and an FFmpeg manually built version of the current FFmpeg versions to date (4.2.1 / 15.10.2019).

Should you need the build script configuration and or library versions used (just ask).

I had the same issue as the OP but couldn't use his solution.

The full versions was with the interrupt callback I used was:

```
    int interruptCallBack(void *ctx){
    RTSPProviderObject *whyFFmpeg = (__bridge RTSPProviderObject*)ctx;
    NSLog(@"What is this!");
    if(whyFFmpeg.whatIsHappeningSTR) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The return value 1 should have interrupted the `av_read_frame()` and exited without a crash as to my current understanding.

It still crashed. My solution was to let `av_read_frame()` finish reading and terminate the session context which will be freed and don't allow any more reading. This was easy since I had this issue when I deallocated my `RTSPProviderObject` and no reading was done.

The final usage was:

```
[self.rtspProvider cleanup];
self.rtspProvider = nil;
```

Below is the full code snippet:

```
#import "Don't forget the required ffmpeg headers or header file"

int interruptCallBack(void *ctx){
    RTSPProviderObject *whyFFmpeg = (__bridge RTSPProviderObject*)ctx;
    NSLog(@"What is this!");
    if(whyFFmpeg.whatIsHappeningSTR) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@interface RTSPProviderObject ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) AVFormatContext *sessionContext;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *whatIsHappeningSTR;
@property (nonatomic, assign) AVDictionary *sessionOptions;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL usesTcp;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isInputStreamOpen;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLock *audioPacketQueueLock;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLock *packetQueueLock;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableArray *audioPacketQueue;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int selectedVideoStreamIndex;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int selectedAudioStreamIndex;
@end


@implementation RTSPProviderObject

- (id _Nullable)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    self.sessionContext = NULL;
    self.sessionContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = self.sessionContext;
    if (!pFormatCtx)
    {
        // Error handling code...
    }

    // MUST be called before avformat_open_input().
    av_dict_free(&_sessionOptions);

    self.sessionOptions = 0;
    if (self.usesTcp)
    {
        // "rtsp_transport" - Set RTSP transport protocols.
        // Allowed are: udp_multicast, tcp, udp, http.

        av_dict_set(&_sessionOptions, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
    }   

    // Open an input stream and read the header with the demuxer options.
    // rtspURL - connection url to your remote ip camera which supports RTSP 2.0.
    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, rtspURL.UTF8String, NULL, &_sessionOptions) != 0)
    {
        self.isInputStreamOpen = NO;
       // Error handling code...
    }

    self.isInputStreamOpen = YES;

    // user-supplied AVFormatContext pFormatCtx might have been modified.
    self.sessionContext = pFormatCtx;
    pFormatCtx->interrupt_callback.callback = interruptCallBack;
    pFormatCtx->interrupt_callback.opaque = (__bridge void *)(self);

    // ... Other needed but currently not relevant code for codec/stream and other setup.
}

- (BOOL)prepareNextFrame
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    int isVideoFrameAvailable = 0;

    // The session context is needed to provide frame data. Frame data is provided for video and audio.
    // av_read_frame reads from pFormatCtx.
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = self.sessionContext;
    if (!pFormatCtx) { return NO; }

    // Audio packet access is forbidden.
    [self.packetQueueLock lock];
    BOOL readResult = YES;
    // Calling av_read_frame while it is reading causes a bad_exception.
    // We read frames as long as the session context cotains frames to be read and cosumed (usually one).
    while (!isVideoFrameAvailable && self.isInputStreamOpen && readResult) {
        if (packet.buf == nil && self.whatIsHappeningSTR) {
            [self.packetQueueLock unlock];
            return NO;
        }
        NSLog(@"New frame will be read.");
        if (self.shouldTerminateStreams) {
            [self terminate];
            [self.packetQueueLock unlock];
            return NO;
        }
        readResult = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >=0;
        // Video packet data decoding.
        // We need to make sure that the frame video data which is consumed matches the user selected stream.
        if(packet.stream_index == self.selectedVideoStreamId) {

            // DEPRECIATED:
            // avcodec_decode_video2(self.videoCodecContext, self.rawFrameData, &isVideoFrameAvailable, &packet);
            // Replaced by this new implememtation. Read more: https://blogs.gentoo.org/lu_zero/2016/03/29/new-avcodec-api/
            // *
            // We need the video context to decode video data.
            AVCodecContext *videoContext = self.videoCodecContext;
            if (!videoContext && videoContext->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) { isVideoFrameAvailable = 1; }

            int ret;
            // Supply raw packet data as input to a decoder.
            ret = avcodec_send_packet(videoContext, &packet);

            if (ret < 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"codec: sending video packet failed");
                [self.packetQueueLock unlock];
                return NO;
            }

            // Return decoded output data from a decoder.
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(videoContext, self.rawFrameData);
            if (isVideoFrameAvailable < 0 && isVideoFrameAvailable != AVERROR(EAGAIN) && isVideoFrameAvailable != AVERROR_EOF)
            {
                [self.packetQueueLock unlock];
                return NO;
            }

            if (ret >= 0) { isVideoFrameAvailable = 1; }
            // *
        } else {
            // avcodec_decode_video2 unreference all the buffers referenced by self.rawFrameData and reset the frame fields.
            // We must do this manually if we don't use the video frame or we will leak the frame data.
            av_frame_unref(self.rawFrameData);
            isVideoFrameAvailable = 1;
        }

        // Audio packet data consumption.
        // We need to make sure that the frame audio data which will be consumed matches the user selected stream.
        if (packet.stream_index == self.selectedAudioStreamIndex) {

            [self.audioPacketQueueLock lock];

            [self.audioPacketQueue addObject:[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&packet length:sizeof(packet)]];

            [self.audioPacketQueueLock unlock];
        }

    }

    [self.packetQueueLock unlock];

    return isVideoFrameAvailable!=0;
}

- (void)cleanup
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    self.shouldTerminateStreams = YES;
    self.whatIsHappeningSTR = @"";
}

- (void)terminate
{
    avformat_close_input(&_sessionContext);
}

@end
```

Hope this helps anyone. Thank you for reading and contributing.